# Diffing remote branches with msysgit

Tags: windows, git, diff, fetch, msysgit

I'm trying to get my team to use git and since most of them want a GUI then I've gone down the msysgit path.  I have a nice set of instructions written up for most daily tasks but I'm stumped on how to do code reviews.  To keep it simple, I'm telling each of them to create a branch with their name using master as the starting point, then stage/commit changes locally and push to a central repository where other devs can fetch their changes for review.  My plan was to have them checkout another dev's changes in a detached head state and then have them diff against master.  In bash terms, it would look like this:

```
git checkout origin/fred
git diff -w origin/master
```

I can get the GUI to checkout a remote branch as a detached head without a problem, but I can't seem to find a way to diff against another branch, local or remote.  The UI happily shows changes on the local branch but for code reviews we need to see changes against the current production code.  Any ideas on how this can be done?  Is there another Git Windows client that's better than msysgit?

Comment: You don't have to have anything checked out, `git diff commit1 commit2` will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find msysgit overly limiting when it comes to GUI features.  I prefer [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) and a healthy list of [aliases](http://davidwalsh.name/git-aliases) from the Git command-line.  For example I've rigged `git ext` to be `!start /b gitextensions` which nicely pulls up the Git Extensions history pane.  If I'm in the mood to commit via GUI, I have rigged `git commit-ext` to run `!start /b gitextensions commit`.

Another invaluable tool is [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) and when [rigged](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitwindows) into git does wonderful things.